# When I try to load an (unpacked) extension into Edge, why does it say that web_accessible_resources[0] is invalid?

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-extension, microsoft-edge-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I'm building a browser extension for Microsoft Edge in which I need to inject a script into certain pages. Whenever I try to load the unpacked extension, Edge reports, “**Error** Invalid value for 'web_accessible_resources[0]'.” However, I've looked at [the documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/manifest/web_accessible_resources/) and some examples and it appears that I have a valid configuration. Below is a minimum working example to reproduce the error:

---

### manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,

    "name": "MWE",
    "version": "0.0.0",

    "web_accessible_resources": [{
        "resources": ["script.js"],
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"]
    }]
}
```

### script.js

<empty>

---

I'm using Microsoft Edge Version 86.0.622.69 (Official build) (64-bit). Why am I getting this error? What can I do to resolve this? I'm able to use Manifest v2 with success, but I want to use Manifest v3.

Comment: For testing, I copied your code of manifest and script file. kept script file and empty and added one console. In both scenarios, it's working fine. So can you please provide more details so I can try to help you in a better way.

Comment: What others details do you want? I provided the browser (along with its version) as well as the entire project structure for the MWE. Are you using the same version of Edge?

Comment: Yes, @tyler I am using the same version of Edge. I don't know what is the cause of your problem but it's working fine for me. I wanted to debug it so also added a service worker which simply prints the details of the extension on the extension install. and it's also working fine even without any warning. If you want I can add my code for your reference in the answer box.

Comment: How did you build the "content_scripts" section in the manifest?

Comment: @Robbi, The error occurs with or without `content_scripts`.

Comment: If I remember correctly, MV3 was introduced in Chromium with version 89.
If Edge follows the same versioning label then we have certainly found the problem 'cause you state you are using 86.0.622.69.
If you want to experience the mv3 you'll have to update that browser; Let me suggest you at least a 91.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried using the Manifest v2 format for `web_accessible_resources`. It loaded successfully, but it had a background error that said, “The maximum currently-supported manifest version is 2, but this is 3. Certain features may not work as expected.” I guess that solves that. Microsoft's documentation didn't make that clear.